# Can I dynamically load an executable on linux?

Tags: python, c, linux, dynamic-linking

I wrote a little testing framework that uses 'nm' to inspect shared libraries and look for test functions. I then use Python's ctypes library to dynamically load the shared object and execute the test functions. Is there a way to do this with an executable? When I tried the same trick on an executable module Python reported that it could not dynamically load an executable.

Comment: What are the compile flags you used to build the .SO when python complained?

Comment: SO worked fine, it was when I build an executable that things didn't work. For the exe I used: g++ -Wl,-rpath,. -Wl,-rpath-link,build/debug/final -o build/debug/final/dummy build/debug/intermediate/dummy/projects/dummy/main.o

Comment: if you add the `-shared` arg, is it no longer executable?

Answer (score 3):

If this is your own application you could rearrange the build so your executable is only `main() { real_main(); }` and `real_main()` is in `libapp.so`.  Then you could test `libapp.so` with your existing code.

If it's possible to load another executable it probably involves loading `ld.so` and getting it to do the work.  If you run `/lib/ld-linux.so` (on Linux) it will print a stanza with information.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I could move all of my code to a shared object. I am building tools for a team though so I would rather not force that on all my programmers.

Answer (score 1):

Try linking the executable with the `-pie` option (if you have the possibility to do so).

(found this option on [this feature request](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11754) for adding support to `dlopen` an executable -- `dlopen` is what is used to load a shared object).

Comment: Thanks! that was a great pointer. In addition to -pie I also had to link with -Wl,--export-dynamic. Worked wonderfully.

Comment: @samwise: you can also pass `-rdynamic` to the compiler driver, if `-Wl,--export-dynamic` feels too verbose...

Comment: @samwise: or, if you don't want to export all symbols from the executable, use `--dynamic-list` as explained in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292473/how-to-call-function-in-executable-from-my-library/6298434#6298434