# Shared Library Object File Linkage

Tags: c++, c, dll, linker, shared-libraries

I'm interested in solutions for the question below for Linux and Windows, GCC, MinGW, and MSVC (if possible).

I have an application that I've written that supports user-defined shared library imports (add on modules). The application scans a directory, finds *.dll files or *.so files, and loads them dynamically at runtime.

So far, all the user modules have been completely composed of self sufficient code. That is, the object files that make up the DLL/SO yielded no incomplete references from the point of view of the linker.

No I want to allow the modules to be able to use functions that are compiled into object files that make up the binary application that is importing these modules. In other words, **I want to allow them to use some of my library code, without having to be compiled into the DLL/SO itself.** Unfortunately, in the linker phase when building the DLL/SO, this fails with the complaint that there are unresolved symbols.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a library with the code you want to share between the user module and your program.
Now the user program and your program can link with this new library.

Answer (score 1):

why not just make a DLL which is linked by both the main app and all the user libs... this is perfectly legal, safe and does what you want AFAICT.

Answer (score 1):

As for Linux and other ELF platforms, this is perfectly possible. You just need to export the appropriate symbols from your executable, and they will be preferred over the same symbols at the dynamic library. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6292473/371250) for details.

As suggested by one of the answers to that question, you could instead pass the functions you want to export as callbacks to some initialization function in the dynamic library.

Answer (score 0):

my first thought is: figure out another way to do this... require the add-ons to communicate via a known interface type, and then there will be no need to try to trick the linker...