# Call functions in the main executable from a shared object

Tags: c++, posix, freebsd, elf

I have to call functions in the main executable from a shared library loaded with LD_PRELOAD.

The executable exports all symbols and contains debug information. Unfortunately I don't have access to it's source code.

Currently I'm getting undefined symbol errors when trying to load that shared library.
Is there a way to do this?

PS: 
Target platform is FreeBSD/x86.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to call function in executable from my library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292473/how-to-call-function-in-executable-from-my-library)

Comment: No, my question is a bit different since I don't have the main executable's source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you create a function pointer by doing a typedef and use 'dlsym()' to get the address
of the symbol. You can then invoke the function through the function pointer like a normal
function call. Note: You do not need dlopen() since the main executable with symbols exported
is loaded into process address space.

Prototype:

```
void *dlsym(void *handle, const char *symbol);
```

Assume the exported function is:

```
int foo(char *arg);
```

Your function pointer:

```
typedef (int)(*fooPtr)(char *);
```

In you code:

```
/* You can send NULL for first argument */
fooPtr fp = dlsym(NULL, "foo");
assert(0 != fp);
int ret = fp("hello world");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gcc -Wl,--export-dynamic
```

...should do the trick.

[Documentation on --export-dynamic](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#index-g_t_002d_002dno_002dexport_002ddynamic-34)

Comment: As I said I don't have access to the main executable's source.

Comment: Then I think you are out of luck.  You can only reference exported symbols.

Comment: Hmm, there's no way to generate the dynamic export table? IDA shows me all exported functions + the executable was compiled with debug information

Comment: Good question.  I hope you find an answer :-)