# Manipulating the symbol resolution order for dynamic library loading

Tags: c++, linux

I'm trying to manipulate (or at least better understand) the symbol resolution order when loading dynamic libraries at runtime.  In my example here I am using dlopen on a Linux OS.

I'm trying to get the dynamically loaded interpreter library "libmyint.so" to link with the function "message_from_library" in the shared object library "libmylib.so" and not with the "libmylib.a"  that is linked into the application "myapp" which is what I currently have.

[code.tar.gz](http://www.filedropper.com/codetar)

[1](http://www.filedropper.com/codetar) contains an archive of a simple example to understand this better.  The following is the instructions on how to build the example and run it.

Instructions to build:

```
tar xzf code.tar.gz
mkdir app-build int-build lib-build
cd lib-build
cmake ../lib
make
cd ../int-build
cmake ../int
make
cd ../app-build
cmake ../app
make

./myapp
```

Actual output:

```
Call to statically linked interpreter function.
This message is from a static interpreter library object.
This message is from a static library object.
Call to dynamically loaded function in interpreter library.
This message is from a *shared* interpreter library object.
This message is from a static library object.
```

Desired output:

```
Call to statically linked interpreter function.
This message is from a static interpreter library object.
This message is from a static library object.
Call to dynamically loaded function in interpreter library.
This message is from a *shared* interpreter library object.
This message is from a *shared* library object.
```

I'm hoping someone can tell me how to get the desired output in this example.

Thanks.

Comment: Dup of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292473/how-to-call-function-in-executable-from-my-library ?

Answer (score 0):

A dynamic library is used to resolve at runtime unresolved references. Anything that's already resolved at link time simply won't produce an unresolved reference. No matter *what* your dynamic linker tries, if there's no unresolved reference `Foo` then it can't resolve that at all.